Fair Cost Distribution for Group Travel
Optimization Problem: Fair Cost Distribution for Group Travel
Problem Statement
I have an interesting optimization problem related to fair cost distribution for group travel. Here are the details:

We have a group of 8 friends traveling together.
We're using 3 cars for the trip, with different running costs:

Car 1: 60€
Car 2: 30€
Car 3: 20€


These costs include highway taxes (9€ per car), which are unavoidable.
Everyone in the group will use all three cars during the trip.

The Challenge
We want to find a fair way to split the costs, but we've encountered some issues:

If we split the total cost (110€) equally among 8 people, each person would pay 13.75€. However, this means the owner of Car 3 would receive money (20€ - 13.75€ = 6.25€), which doesn't even cover their tax costs.

We can't simply have each car owner cover their own costs, as everyone is using all the cars.


Question
What would be an optimal way to distribute these costs? We're looking for a solution that:

Covers all expenses
Minimizes the burden on the owner of the least expensive car
Fairly distributes the cost among all participants
Potentially asks the owners of more expensive cars to bear a larger burden

I've tried various approaches, including equal splitting and proportional distribution based on car costs, but haven't found a satisfactory solution. Any mathematical or algorithmic approaches to solve this optimization problem would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Notes

This problem could be generalized to situations with different numbers of participants and cars, so a scalable solution would be ideal.
I'm open to solutions using linear programming, game theory, or any other relevant mathematical techniques.

Thank you in advance for your insights and solutions!

Taking the mean is the only fair distribution of the costs, the owner of the cheapest car could not make the tour without the expensive car with your assumption. So it is better to change to a meal for 8 people, 1 buying ingredients for 20$ one for 30$ one for 60$, you will not have doubts, that everyone has to pay the 13.75$, the problem of the one with the 20$ expense vanishes.

But that doesn't seem fair. What would be the advantage of spliting the costs and not taking my car alone and pay for my expenses alone? Imagine for instance that for some reason the 1st and 2nd car endup costing 200€ together with mine at 20€ .

Than you have to change your assumption of equally sharing all three cars. The owner of the 20$ car can take the trip alone and pax the 20$ , or take two others with him who pay  each 1/3 so about 7$ so he still has 7$ to pay. Your assumption says the tour only happens with the 3 different cars, therefore the example with the meal is better.
